# Convert octal or decimal number to decimal string

Tags: javascript, string

I have input variables that are of type `number` and can start with any digit, including 0. 
I want to convert the input numbers to a (decimal) string but have trouble doing so.

Using the `String(number)` function works if the number does not start with a 0, but fails when it does since it perceives it as an octal number. 
Using the `number.toString()` function works if the number starts with a 0, but fails when it does not. This drops the starting 0 by the way, which is not a problem for my further analysis.

**Example**

```
var num1 = 0123456;
var num2 = 123456;

var s1 = String(num1); // returns "42798"  -> wanted "0123456"
var s2 = String(num2); // returns "123456" -> correct

var s1 = num1.toString(8); // returns "123456" -> correct
var s2 = num2.toString(8); // returns "361100" -> wanted "123456"
```

I can not find any alternatives to these functions. I have also tried to come up with a way to identify whether the first digit is a 0, but I could not find any effective ways.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not possible. When a number literal starts with a 0, it's interpreted as octal. But the number itself is just a number - it does not somehow remember that it came from a literal that was written using octal syntax. So when formatting, there's no way to know that the number was originally specified with an octal literal.

Comment: Where do the numbers that start with a 0 come from? If you put them in the code yourself, then I suggest manually removing the 0 so that all numbers are decimal (a regex search/replace should do that easily for you).

Comment: I recommend against accepting 0 leading numbers, as octal literals and octal escape sequences are deprecated and will throw a SyntaxError in strict mode. With ECMAScript 2015 and later, the standardized syntax uses a leading zero followed by a lowercase or uppercase Latin letter "O" (0o or 0O).

Comment: How can you keep the 0 when this is not string??

Answer (score 0):

```
const num1 = 0123456;
const num2 = 123456;


const s1 = num1.toString(8); // output 123456
const s2 = num2.toString(10);// output 123456
console.log(s1);
console.log(s2);
```

please use **10** for num2 value

Comment: That would solve the problem, but how to identify whether a number starts with a 0? I do not know this in advance (the provided numbers are just examples to illustrate the problem)